# Why aren't railways being used to help ease the shortage of fuel in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, transportation

Currently the UK is experiencing a shortage of fuel for road vehicles, this being driven by panic-buying by millions of motorists, which in turn has been driven by a shortage of HGV drivers to deliver (said) goods.

Something that has occured to myself during this turbulent period is why the railways/railroads are not used more extensively to ease this pressure on supply chains. I point this out for the reason (which may just be my perception) that there is an extensive railway network throughout the UK which primarily transports people, with goods being a secondary concern (from personal experience it is a rare sight to see goods trains, most that I've seen have been transporting coal/gravel.)
Railways are just one example, but other means of local transport could also be used including canals and costal boats.

Has the UK Government indicated that any other means of transport might be used?

Is there any reason to not used existing infrastructure, such as railways, to ease this pressure on logistics?

Comment: You would still  need trucks to get it to the rail stations and to the final destinations.  Not to mention you need the equipment to transport it by train and I am guessing that they don't have that and it will take a while to get what they need. Overall I am not sure this is a politics question but a logistics question and not suitable for this site.

Comment: Rail built for freight can usually accommodate passenger cars (this is how most of US rail operates).  But rail built for passenger car use may very well not be suitable for freight usage. A rough analogy would be a bridge built for cars can handle the weight of people but the reverse is almost certainly not true.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question because it is a question about the feasibility of a potential solution to a current problem faced by the United Kingdom.  In other words, it is a question about policy, so it is explicitly on topic under the definition advanced in the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: "Currently the UK is experiencing a shortage of fuel for road vehicles": at the pumps, specifically. Apparently, we have plenty of fuel - it's just in the wrong place, due to the aforementioned shortage of lorry drivers.

Comment: @eps - railways in the UK, and most other other countries that use 'heavy' (traditional) rail, are built to handle the heaviest trains likely to be used, including freight.

Comment: Just because the OP has not seen many freight trains, that does not mean that there aren't many. Total UK freight moved was 4.33 billion net tonne kilometres in first quarter  2021-22. Every year, freight trains transport goods worth about £30bn, and rail freight contributes around £1 billion to the economy each year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the railways is not a short-term solution.

- To transport fuel (or anything, really) by rail you need the appropriate cars. These do exist but are in us in day-to-day operations and cannot easily be taken out of service for something else.
- Especially for liquid goods that aren't or cannot be containerised, you need special loading and unloading facilities which are not common outside large-scale customers such as refineries. Even the number of regular goods yards has been decreasing constantly through the years.
- Track access needs to be sorted (but that might just be the least of all problems).
- Wherever your loading and unloading facilities are, you still need to get the goods from there to the final sales point (e.g. the petrol station) by road vehicle. As extensive as the railway network is, the road network is an order of magnitude more.
- Trains also need drivers albeit fewer per ton.
- (other points I have failed to think of right now)

The canal network is even less extensive than the railway network but additionally suffers from lack of appropriate vessels. The canals in the UK typically predate the railways or are contemporaneous with early railways. At the time, boats and barges were much smaller. Nowadays, canals are built to much greater dimensions and overhead clearances to allow for larger vessels and the smaller ones have essentially disappeared. For visualisation, take a look at the boats that travel up or down the Rhine (Europe's most used inland waterway by a mile) and imagine whether you could see one of those navigating the Grand Union Canal.

Canals (and rivers) were once the cheapest and most efficient ways to get goods from one place to another. In the 19th century, railways took that spot. Compared to road transport at the time, railways – while slow by our modern standards – were much faster and could carry much more per trip. Therefore, facilities for loading or unloading goods were present at practically every station and all larger plants would have direct rail access.

In the 20th century, the internal combustion engine and later the diesel engine changed the economics yet again. As trains are relatively inflexible (it is difficult taking out just a single car and doing so stops the entire train), lorries became the preferred method to transport just about everything; initially to and from a train station but ultimately also from a producer to an end user. On the other side, rail transport concentrated more an more on long-running long trains or high-tonnage transport where it had traditionally excelled. This development of over a century cannot be quickly undone to combat a crisis short-term.

Comment: "It is difficult taking out just a single car and doing so stops the entire train)" https://99percentinvisible.org/article/slip-coaches-back-when-british-express-trains-detached-passenger-cars-at-speed/

Comment: Good answer. The canal network isn't integrated with modern transport at all (no port/loading facilities) and even using seaports wouldn't work because there are comparatively few active seaports in the UK, many specialised for particular goods (e.g. containers or dry bulk goods), and the vast majority of them depend on lorry drivers to move goods away from them. And, very importantly, petrol is highly flammable so you need a lot of precautions and special infrastructure to unload and transport it.